# storing items in a map under multiple keys

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a std::map with key_type and mapped_type. Every instance of mapped_type is inserted into the map as 3 copies - under 3 different key values. This allows me to retrieve the value based on any of the 3 keys.

But the drawback is that when I want to delete the item, I need to look for 3 keys instead of just one, in order to get rid of all 3 copies.

Is it possible to compose the 3 keys into one class and be able to compare such object with 1 key, while maintaing a strict weak ordering? In such scenario, how would the operator< look like for key_type?

EDIT: The 3 keys are of the same type e.g. a single record is accessible with 3 different integer values (and those key values are not used by any other record). So from what I understand Boost.MultiIndex is not a solution for this problem.

Comment: The question is unclear. Where does 3 keys come into the picture, when for each *value* there can be only one *key*?

Comment: @Nawaz The value is stored as 3 copies - each copy under different key.

Comment: So, for example, an address book where a person can have multiple phone numbers and you need to be able to lookup by phone number?

Answer (score 2):

Use Boost.MultiIndex.  See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort

Comment: I updated the question. If I understood the idea of Boost.MultiIndex, it is for cases where keys are of different types, so it's not appropriate for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using two data structures encapsulated into a single object:

- `std::list<Node> list;`
- `std::map<Key, std::list<Node>::iterator> map;`

where `Node` contains:

- `Value value;`
- and 3 instances `std::map<Key, std::list<Node>::iterator>::iterator i1, i2, i3;`

You can then insert and remove values with appropriate bookkeeping to ensure that the structures remain consistent.